# Security warning related to frames appears when surfing the internet

Tags: macos, high-sierra, security, internet

I changed my computer password yesterday and now when using the internet I often get a security warning related to frames. I don't know what frame it is referring to since I'm not sure what they are or how to use them. The warning message is a pop-up and is shown below.

[image: Security Image]

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to turn it off? I'm running High Sierra on my iMac using Safari to surf the internet.

Comment: Does this happen on the Stack Exchange network? That's been happening to me. I think it's website-specific

Comment: Yes it does. I didn't even consider it might be website-specific.  Thank you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265627/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-on

Comment: Thats pretty much a non-answer. this has been around 5 years and just now started to appear on my computer?